# mailgun email validation response

Tags: c#, email-validation, mailgun

I am a newbie to Mailgun and REST and need some help.

If I use the Mailgun provided code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2";
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "xxxx");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/address/validate";
request.AddParameter("address", "me@mydomain.com");
return client.Execute(request);
```

How do I retrieve and process the response that the address is valid or not?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. I didn't use RESTClient and wrote my own code(which works perfectly fine)

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static object GetEmailInfo(string UserName)
    {
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate?address=" + UserName);
        http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("api","public key");
        http.Timeout = 5000;
        try
        {
            var response = http.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JSON.JsonObject js = new JSON.JsonObject(content);
            return Convert.ToBoolean(js["is_valid"]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **First of** You should never post private information such as your public key of such API

Just by using the amazing [**Postman Chrome app**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) you can see the result of such request:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsWGD.png) to see the image below in full resolution

[image]

and I'm sure, if you instead of `return client.Execute(request);` you do

```
var result = client.Execute(request);
return result;
```

and adding a breakpoint in the `return` you can inspect what is the object that is passed from the call... without testing, I'm sure you can convert `result.Content` (as it's where RestSharp appends the response content) into an object and use that object (or use the `dynamic` type).

---

now, testing your code in VS:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZoV.png) to see the image below in full resolution

[image]

you can then use the `dynamic` object like:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN1sZ.png) to see the image below in full resolution

[image]

```
public void GetResponse()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2";
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "pubkey-e82c8201c292691ad889ace3434df6cb");

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Resource = "/address/validate";
    request.AddParameter("address", "me@mydomain.com");

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    dynamic content = Json.Decode(response.Content);

    bool isValid = content.is_valid;
    string domain = content.parts.domain;
}
```

and treat the content of the response just like the json passed:

```
{
    "address": "me@mydomain.com",
    "did_you_mean": null,
    "is_valid": true,
    "parts": {
        "display_name": null,
        "domain": "mydomain.com",
        "local_part": "me"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using:

dynamic content = System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.Decode(response.Content);

But am getting the error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Decode' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: addded: using Newtonsoft.Json;

and changed code to:
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

Now it works

Comment: `Json.Decode` is from `System.Web.Helpers`. If the answer helped you in some way, mark it as correct answer and let others see that for your question, there's a correct answer.